# Gmail inbox does not show in Safari

Tags: safari, gmail

I have a mid 2009 MBP with OSX 10.11.6 and Safari 11.0.2, and my problem is with Safari.

For many months, possibly for the past year, when I display my gmail account it is usually the case that the display has to be reloaded numerous times before the usual parts of the gmail display are shown.

The usual display has 3 or 4 separate parts: the top line has the google search bar and 4 icons to the right; the second line has button options relating to the list of emails; below these two lines are two columns, the left showing the labels associated with 'saved' emails, and the right column - the bulk of the whole display - showing (first) unread and (then) read emails in the inbox. When I logon to gmail it is usually the case that the inbox part does not show, but does show after multiple reloads. Occasionally, along with this no-show, the other parts of the display are messed up in a way that is hard to describe.

Does anyone have an idea of what's happening here? Could Flash be a culprit here? I mention Flash because it gives me problems in Safari that I can overcome by switching to Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: How about a screenshot of the issue? It would go a long way.

Comment: Try the basic HTML version of GMail https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/1pq68r75kzvdr/?v%3Dlui